# Displaying an image in the face of rotating cube in VisPy

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, data-visualization, vispy

I have played with [this example](http://vispy.org/examples/basics/gloo/rotate_cube.html) of VisPy to show a rotating cube. Is there a way to load an image (e.g. a png) and display it as one of the faces of the cube?

Answer (score 4):

You can use imageio for reading image data (get it via `pip install imageio`) and then use it as a texture:

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('/path/to/image.png')
texture.set_data(im)  # use image as texture
```

Bonus points, show a video on the cube:

```
reader = imageio.read('/path/to/movie.mp4')
# somwhere in a timer callback
texture.set_data(reader.get_next_data())
```

Comment: nice! this answers to the first part of the question (loading an image) - but how to you access the texture object, for instance from vispy's ``vispy.scene.visuals.Cube`` class?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Mesh class supports textures yet. If it does not, it should be added at some point. I'd recommend opening an issue for it.